# What is meant by the statement about "minifig replicas" in the 2020/2 catalogue?

Tags: star-wars, marketing

The German Lego catalogue for the second half of 2020 contains several instances of a confusing statement on page 125:

> Jedes Set enthält die detailgetreue Nachbildung einer original LEGO Star Wars Minifigur.

In English:

> Each set contains the detailed replica of an original LEGO Star Wars minifigure.

This statement (that appears twice on the same page, once related to a minifigure of Leia Organa, once related to one of Luke Skywalker) leaves me utterly confused:

- What is special about these figures?
- Don't all the sets contain LEGO Star Wars minifigures?
- Aren't all of them "original" (because they're produced by LEGO for the Star Wars product line)?
- Then why are these figures "replicas"? What's the difference between a minifigure and a replica of a minifigure if both are (presumably) produced in the same factory, using the same moulds?

**What is that statement supposed to mean?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These 2 sets [75243 & 75258](https://catalogs.lego.com/BrandCatalog/2hy2020/de/bc-2hy-2020-dea/?page=125#/) are 2 of the 20 years anniversary sets.

LEGO included in each of these sets an additional minifig on a stand based on the minifigs released during the first years. These initial star wars figures still had the yellow heads before they moved to flesh colored heads. So they have recreated / replicated these original minifigs.

The original (2000) minifig: [princess-leia](https://brickset.com/minifigs/sw0026/princess-leia)

[image]

The new replica (2020): [princess-leia-(20th-anniversary-torso)](https://brickset.com/minifigs/sw1022/princess-leia-(20th-anniversary-torso))

[image]

For comparison, a modern (2019) version of the same character: [princess-leia-(white-dress-detailed-belt-crooked-smile)](https://brickset.com/minifigs/sw0994/princess-leia-(white-dress-detailed-belt-crooked-smile))

[image]

Comment: Ooh, so "original" refers to the "original, first design" of the minifigure. I see. Somewhat cryptic for readers who do not follow the way the Star Wars minifigures change over the years in depth, thanks :)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Not just Star Wars minifigures. All (human) minifigures were transitioned from the yellow flesh color of the original designs to the modern flesh-toned designs. There's a much more stark contrast in some cases for the Star Wars minifigures because some of them shifted to other tones to replicate the character's appearances more accurately. See Emperor Palpatine for a good example, he's been at least 4 different colors over the years (original yellow, modern flesh tone, dark grey, and a weird flesh-grey color).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn: I see. The things you don't notice when you're primarily interested in the lines that are *not* based on licenses ... ;)

Comment: An important detail is the large print on the back to avoid any confusion with the original minifigure!